# Выскакивающее окошко

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Нужно сделать так, чтобы, например, нажал на кнопку и внизу, где время, выскакивало определенное окошко (как в аське, когда тебе кто-то написал). Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создаем форму.
2. Указываем ее позицию относительно размеров экрана и размеров формы (`top:= Screen.Height - Height; left:= Screen.Width - Width`).
3. При желании можно побаловаться с прозрачностью формы (`AlphaBlend:=true; AlphaBlendValue:=200;`). Например: наводим мышкой на форму, и она показывается на 255, убираем мышку и она исчезает на 200.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Вам доп. компонент нужен. Гляньте в сторону `TrayIcon`. В нем есть всплывающие окна (подсказки).

Comment: а почему самому нельзя создать форму и открывать ее в углу?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, потому, что это - уродство и нужно только для поддержки древних версий шелла, которые не поддерживали baloon tips в notification area.